# j2objc exception prevents unit tests running

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods, j2objc

I'm working on an app that uses a cocoapod, which has been built using j2objc. But when I try to run unit tests in Xcode I see the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'JavaLangArrayStoreException', reason: 'source of type IOSByteArray is not an array'
```

I understand that arrays in Java don't map perfectly onto Objective C arrays. But this exception doesn't prevent the app from running, so is there a way to ignore this for unit tests and UI tests?

The code that's failing is inside a cocoapod, so I'm not sure I'll be able to do any manual conversions. Here's the line that's failing:

```
return IOSObjectArray_Get(nil_chk([rawType getGenericInterfaces]), i);
```

Comment: provide your code

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your code but you must understand that array of Objective-C is not -the same as `IOSByteArray`!

You have to convert `IOSByteArray` into usual objc array before using of it.

use either this

```
- (void)getBytes:(jbyte *)buffer
          offset:(jint)offset
          length:(jint)length;
```

or this

`- (NSData *)toNSData;`

method to work.

Comment: See the amended question. Converting the IOSByteArray would be the ideal solution, but I don't have direct access to it as it's inside a cocoapod. Also the exception doesn't cause the app to crash when I run it, so it would be good if there was a way to just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like the line that's failing. That error message is from System.arraycopy, which failed saying that IOSByteArray isn't a subclass of IOSArray, [which it is](https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/jre_emul/Classes/java/lang/System.java#L131). IOSObjectArray only throws an ArrayStoreException [here](https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/jre_emul/Classes/IOSObjectArray.m#L123), with a different error message.

Do you have the source to the unit test, and if so, can you post it or its project (if it's open-source)? If you [file a j2objc issue](https://github.com/google/j2objc/issues/new) with the failing test, you'll be notified as soon as it's fixed.

If this is a JUnit test, you can surround the failing line with a try/catch block just like in Java. Or comment it out. ;-)